# How to name those two buttons to switch from effective attendees to invitees

Tags: usability, user-behavior, user-expectation, terminology, mobile-application

I own an app that suggest an event to some users I chose.
So I select, let's say, 40 invitees and I expect some of them (or all of them) to effectively participate to my event.

I want to have two columns, in the screen of my event's details, allowing me to switch between the list of all invitees that haven't participated yet, and attendees that have participated (meaning they clicked on : "I will be there !").

Question:  How to name those two buttons switching columns so that any users can understand their meaning in 1 second?

I would choose "Participants" / "Attendees"  but any participants are in fact an attendees that has participated, so I can't make this distinction..

I would choose "Participants" / "Pending" but it's not meaningful.

Any good UX-oriented idea? :)

Comment: It has not to be a single word. Has it?

Comment: I prefer a single second of understanding than a single word ;)

Comment: "Confirmed participants" and "Pending confirmations"?

Comment: In french, "pending confirmations" is "confirmations en attente". 
A big too long, isn't it?

Comment: Ahhhh in French...

Comment: No it doesn't have to be focused on french. No matter the language is, I want first the best words. That's only secondary that those words should be pretty..short. (a bonus)

Comment: I thought about:  "They said yes / they haven't said yes yet"

Comment: Confirmed/Unconfirmed or Attendees/Unconfirmed but well I'd guess each language has a better wording...

Comment: I chose :  "Attendees/expected"

Answer (score 1):

Facebook events have a very clear distinction between "Going", "Maybe" and "Invited" (though I wish it it had an option to ask those maybes to switch to a definite yes or no, maybe a week before the actual event).

Answer (score 0):

[I take it you want to show *either*  • those who *are* participating  *or*  • those who *are not* participating -- such that these two sets add to the list of invitees.]

Speaking coarsely:

Have "[Show] Invitees — " as hard text, and use radio buttons labelled "Participating" and "Not Participating" (or "Accepted" or whatever).

(I like the idea of using a check-box labelled "not", but I suspect that would be bad practice for some reason.  It does not imply exclusivity… although technically radio buttons does not imply *real-world* alternative-ness either [it is the labels that do that].)

p.s.  There is a practical distinction between those who will participate but have not yet responded… and those who intend to not participate.  You might be best having "Participating", "Not Participating" and (e.g.) "Unknown".  —  You might have "Participating" and "Declined", with those who have not yet responded being not listed either way.

q.s.  Thank-you to the internet for deleting white space added for clarity.